# The handle is invalid when loading file or assembly AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having one error repeatedly. The site is on ASP.NET 2.0 web form. There is no pattern to reproduce this error again because it occurs sometimes and it resolve by adding blank space at end of the in web.config.

What could be the problem?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))
>
> [COMException (0x80070006): The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies. The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))]
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies. The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613

Comment: You should check for handle leakage, perhaps you're using all available handles.

Comment: _"it resolve by adding blank space at end of the in web.config."_ - you mean it is resolved by recycling the application pool, which is a side-effect of modifying the web.config. Your application must indeed be leaking handles, as @Lasse suggests. Some more information about the project would perhaps help, for example the kind of libraries you use.

Comment: Is System.Windows.Forms.Timer causes problem?

Comment: Yes, that class does use handles (as most System.Windows.Forms.* classes do), that if not disposed of properly, can cause problems like you have.

Comment: Why are you using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in an ASP.NET context? Use `System.Timers.Timer` in a server-side situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736 is not compatible with asp.net 2.0**](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/33804)

> Note: The current version of the AJAX Control Toolkit is not
>   compatible with ASP.NET 2.0. The latest version that is compatible
>   with ASP.NET 2.0 can be found here: [20229](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/11121)

Remove current `AjaxControlToolkit` and install compatible version of it.